# Matching array of numbers with array of names

Tags: arrays, sorting, matching

I'm making a quiz game, and I want to make an option to print out the questions in order of how many people got that question right. 
I.E. if two people got question 3 correct, one person got question 1 correct and no-one got question 2 correct, then the order of questions and scores it would show would be:

Question 2 --- score

Question 1 --- score

Question 3 --- score

I've got the object of the question holding the question name and the 'scoreCount' variable which keeps track of the amount of times that person got the question correct. However, I'm struggling to implement this into a method. As it stands I've got the method set up with two arrays; one holding the scores, the other holding the names. What would be the best way to correlate the scores with the names of the question? Below is incomplete and how far I've gotten. It runs into problems when they equal 0.

EDIT: Removed the code. It didn't seem necessary to the actual question being asked.

Comment: If you are struggling to implement the method, please include the method so that we can help you work through it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two arrays, sounds like a SortedMap<int, String> is your friend here (looks like you're using Java), where int is your score count, and String is your question name.

Keep track of your score counts using this SortedMap, and when you iterate through it the order is sorted by the key (in your case, it's the score count). Perfect!

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Good luck with your assignment. I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Hope this helps.